# roslaunch nodes / launch files only available on remote machine?

Tags: roslaunch, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As pointed out in [roslaunch/XML](https://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML)

> Substitution args are currently resolved on the local machine. In other words, environment variables and ROS package paths will be set to their values in your current environment, even for remotely launched processes

Is there any way to use roslaunch to launch nodes or launch files that are only available on a remote machine?

I've checked [this solution](https://answers.ros.org/question/264899/launch-only-remotely-installed-package-on-remote-machine/) but it doesn't seem to be working (nor is it supposed to work).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371480/roslaunch-nodes-/-launch-files-only-available-on-remote-machine?/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2021-02-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-10**:
I don't believe there is a supported way.

I've seen some hacks with Docker images, dummy pkgs and `launch-prefix`, but it's not officially supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming host has ssh key access to remote, I accomplished this with the following:

Host machine launch file:

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="local_pkg" type="remote_bringup.sh" name="remote_bringup"/>
</launch>
```

Host machine `remote_bringup.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

trap 'ssh remote@remote "pkill roslaunch"' INT TERM
ssh remote@remote "~/bringup.sh"
wait
```

Remote machine `bringup.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://host_machine:11311
export ROS_IP=remote_machine
nohup /opt/ros/install/env.sh roslaunch remote_pkg normal.launch &
```

The script properly catches SIGINT, SIGTERM and forwards it to the remote machine's `roslaunch`

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2021-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-10**:
Yes, that's similar to one of the work-arounds I mentioned.

> Remote machine `bringup.sh`
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
> source /opt/ros/install/setup.bash
> export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://host_machine:11311
> export ROS_IP=remote_machine
> nohup roslaunch remote_pkg normal.launch &
> ```

Couldn't you use `/opt/ros/install/env.sh` as a prefix for `roslaunch remote_pkg normal.launch`?

Seems much simpler.

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2021-02-10**:
@gvdhoorn TIL, thx for the tip :D

**Comment by [billnava](https://answers.ros.org/users/65350/billnava/) on 2022-04-16**:
@gvdhoorn Any workaround for windows host machine and ubuntu remote machine?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-04-16**:
Couldn't you still use SSH? There are clients for Windows (as well as servers).

**Comment by [asaglam](https://answers.ros.org/users/45229/asaglam/) on 2023-06-15**:
How to accomplish this as at startup? Let's say, the host runs a script that starts the roslaunch file after the startup automatically. We need to make sure that the remote machine is up if we will execute `ssh remote@remote "~/bringup.sh"`.  What would be the trick to catch this?